# What is it called when there is a lyrical transition to the chorus/hook?

Tags: terminology, lyrics

There are many songs that do this, the latest one I've identified is:

> A$AP Mob - Yamborghini High (Official Music Video) ft. Juicy J ([youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tt7gP_IW-1w),[genius](https://genius.com/A-ap-mob-yamborghini-high-lyrics))

Specifically this line here:

> `She make no mistakes, me make no complaints 
>   I love how she think she graduated with that brain
>   She go to…
>   Yamborghini high`

([youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tt7gP_IW-1w&feature=youtu.be&t=60), [genius](https://genius.com/8618752))

The comment on Genius for this verse even mentions it's a "clever transition". It's clever because the last line in the verse, is the start of a sentence that continues with the chorus.

> "The last bar of the verse is a clever transition to the hook"

I am fascinated by this transition from verse to the chorus. Does this "clever transition" have a name?

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of like an *elision* where the end of one phrase is the beginning of the next phrase. The verb is *elide.*

In music elision is specifically about *the notes* overlapping in phrases. But, there is a general meaning for elision as some kind of overlapping or omission.

This may not be the correct usage for elision, but it's the word that came immediately to mind.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it might be an [anacrusis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacrusis) to the chorus that is also part of the verse. There may be no term for it at all, but if there is its probably poetry related.